# Error running npm start command

Tags: reactjs, firebase, ubuntu-16.04

Actually I am making a collaborative text editor using React js and I am getting this error again and  again when I am trying to run npm start command`:

```
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: ENOSPC: no space left on device, watch '/home/lakshay/Desktop/edit/public'
    at FSWatcher.start (fs.js:1409:26)
    at Object.fs.watch (fs.js:1446:11)
    at createFsWatchInstance (/home/lakshay/Desktop/edit/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:37:15)
    at setFsWatchListener (/home/lakshay/Desktop/edit/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:80:15)
    at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._watchWithNodeFs (/home/lakshay/Desktop/edit/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:228:14)
    at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._handleDir (/home/lakshay/Desktop/edit/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:407:19)
    at FSWatcher.<anonymous> (/home/lakshay/Desktop/edit/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:455:19)
    at FSWatcher.<anonymous> (/home/lakshay/Desktop/edit/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:460:16)
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:185:5)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at FSWatcher._handleError (/home/lakshay/Desktop/edit/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/chokidar/index.js:257:10)
    at createFsWatchInstance (/home/lakshay/Desktop/edit/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:39:5)
    at setFsWatchListener (/home/lakshay/Desktop/edit/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:80:15)
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:185:5)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! collabeditor@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the collabeditor@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm.
```

There is likely additional logging output above.

```
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/lakshay/.npm/_logs/2018-07-13T06_10_25_773Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the error message, your disk is full (HDD or SSD), free up some space.

```
Error: ENOSPC: no space left on device
```

Answer (score 3):

`echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | 
 sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p` 
worked in Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Comment: please give some brief about your answer that what you did special?